# Using diverging electric properties for material separation

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science, dielectric, metals

Considering that metals and dielectrics have different behaviours when exposed to an electric field, is there a method that can separate these two materials from a mixture, as per an example, a powder mixture of dielectric and metallic particles?

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed electrostatic separators (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-3020-5_8):

Electrostatic separators depend on the principle that if two bodies are charged alike they repel each other, and if charged oppositely they attract each other. If a mixture of good and poor conductors is fed onto a highly charged conducting surface the good conductors immediately receive a charge similar to that of the surface and are
repelled from it, while the poor conductors are not as ready to receive a charge and continue to adhere.

This is usually accomplished with a rotor-type separator, which is grounded and positive potential ( + ), in the electrical field of a large single, negative potential ( - ) electrode, with the feed particles spilling onto the rotating roll, rapidly developing
a surface charge by induction. The particles that are the better conductors acquire the same potential as the rotor (+) and will then be drawn away from it towards the ( - ) electrode. While the nonconductive particles, less prone to pick up a charge, adhere to the rotor surface until the rotor turns enough for gravity to make the particle fall off."